# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rating'

Tags: python, pandas, функции

Задание: Напишите функцию, которая классифицирует фильмы из материалов занятия по следующим правилам:

- оценка 2 и меньше - низкий рейтинг
- оценка 4 и меньше - средний рейтинг
- оценка 4.5 и 5 - высокий рейтинг

Результат классификации запишите в столбец class

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'\Users\super\Desktop\ratings.csv', sep=' ')
# data.head(5)
def rating_class(row):
    if row.rating>=4.5:
        return 'Фильм имеет высокий рейтинг'
    elif row.rating<4.5:
        return 'Фильм имеет средний рейтинг'
    elif row.rating<=2:
        return 'Фильм имеет низкий рейтинг'
data['class'] = data.apply(rating_class, axis=1)
```

Имеется следующая ошибка кода:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rating'
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: 1) как выглядит ваш `.csv` или `data`? - видимо, у вас нет столбца `rating`. 2) `if/elif` у вас построен неправильно - втрое условие `<4.5` перекрывает третье. 3) лучше для таких задач использовать [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Comment: Еще совет - не используйте точечную нотацию при обращении к столбцам - это плохая практика. вы начинаете путать столбцы датафрейма и методы pandas

Comment: А я вот не уверен, что `axis` правильно указана, может там `axis=0` должно быть, я их вечно путаю.

Comment: Был Excel-файл, название столбцов было перечислено через запятую. Проблема решилась тем, что sep=' ' изменил на sep=',' , тем самым разделив названия столбцов и все получилось.
Всем спасибо за советы, прислушаюсь.